# Spark can't find the application class itself (ClassNotFoundException) in spark-submit with SBT assembly JAR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

## Background

I am trying to get started with Spark using Scala.

Originally, I was trying to write a streaming Kinesis consumer, following along with [this official example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kinesis-asl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisWordCountASL.scala).
Although, at this point I have reduced my error case to remove anything Kinesis related, except for the package dependency, and the error remains the same.

I used SBT to generate an assembly JAR of my project. Then, I tried to run it locally using `spark-submit`. (Detailed steps below.)

This consistently fails with a `ClassNotFoundException`, claiming that it cannot find the main class of my application. (Detailed output below.)

I should emphasize:

To the extent of my understanding, **I don't believe this is the same `ClassNotFoundException` that other posters have seen**, and I don't believe this question is a duplicate of those questions.

In particular, as far as I can tell:

- The class in question is my main application class itself.
- I am referencing the correct fully-qualified class name.
- I have included the dependencies in the output JAR by generating an assembly JAR through SBT.

## Repro steps

1. Initialize empty Scala SBT project. (I used the default template in IntelliJ, but I don't think it matters.)
2. Add project code. (Included below.)
3. `sbt assembly`
4. `./bin/spark-submit --class "sparkpoc.KinesisExample" --master local[4] ~/git/ming-spark-poc/target/scala-2.11/ming-spark-poc-assembly-0.1.jar` (With appropriate substitutions.)

## Error message

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class "sparkpoc.KinesisExample" --master local[4] ~/git/ming-spark-poc/target/scala-2.11/ming-spark-poc-assembly-0.1.jar 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/Users/ming/misc/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-05-09 15:39:01 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkpoc.KinesisExample
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-05-09 15:39:01 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-05-09 15:39:01 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /private/var/folders/py/jrf50pwj1xdd4grjvlg07g580000gp/T/spark-c5f3bade-fbfe-4516-900e-99fee1b47366
```

## My code

### `build.sbt`

```
name := "ming-spark-poc"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % sparkVersion
)

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value
  .copy(includeScala = false)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I'm aware that setting `assemblyMergeStrategy` without a default case fall back is bad practice in production code. This was just a quick hack to get the project to build, and as far as I know, it does not relate to my current error.

### `assembly.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

### `KinesisExample.scala`

Originally, this was a Kinesis consumer.
It's been reduced to a placeholder app that does nothing.
The error has not changed.

```
package sparkpoc

import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object KinesisExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val batchInterval = Seconds(5)

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparcPocKinesisExample")
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, batchInterval)

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

## What I've tried so far

I can run the official examples from the prepackaged JAR with seemingly no issues.

```
$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/Users/ming/misc/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-05-09 16:14:07 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-05-09 16:14:08 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Running Spark version 2.3.0
2018-05-09 16:14:08 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Submitted application: Spark Pi
<SNIPPED>
```

As far as I know, the produced JAR file contains the expected class file. I verified this independently in 2 different ways.

I examined the contents of the JAR with `jar -tf`. It contains the expected class file in the expected location, as far as I can tell.

```
$ jar -tf ./target/scala-2.11/ming-spark-poc-assembly-0.1.jar | grep KinesisExample
org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisExampleUtils$$anonfun$getRegionNameByEndpoint$1.class
org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisExampleUtils$$anonfun$getRegionNameByEndpoint$2.class
org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisExampleUtils$$anonfun$getRegionNameByEndpoint$3.class
org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisExampleUtils$.class
org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisExampleUtils.class
sparkpoc/KinesisExample$.class
sparkpoc/KinesisExample.class
```

I extracted the contents of the JAR with `unzip` and examined them manually. It contains the expected class file in the expected location, as far as I can tell.

While I do not expect anything in this project is current working directory dependent, I repeated the same steps using the Spark installation root as the current working directory, with no change in outcome.

I tried running the generated JAR directly. While I don't expect this to work correctly to actually run the Spark application, I thought it may provide insight into what is going on with class resolution. It fails as follows.

```
$ java -jar ./target/scala-2.11/ming-spark-poc-assembly-0.1.jar "sparkpoc.KinesisExample"
Error: Could not find or load main class sparkpoc.KinesisExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkpoc.KinesisExample
```

I tried renaming the package the class is in, including at one point putting it at the toplevel package (no `package` declaration). Each time, invoking `spark-submit` with the appropriate fully-qualified class name, I still got the same error.

In case the `assemblyMergeStrategy` hack was breaking something indirectly, I tried replacing it with an explicit listing as follows.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "inject", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("mime.types") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

<del>I still got the same error.</del> EDIT: This actually works as expected. I had a separate issue with a stale build artifact. See below.

## Questions

1. Is there anything incorrect or improper about my current SBT setup? (Aside from the hack in `assemblyMergeStrategy`.)
2. How else can I verify that the generated JAR is correct?
3. Supposing that the generated JAR is correct, what else am I missing that could cause such an issue?

**Thank you in advance for any insights or advice you may have.**

## EDIT: Resolution

The answer by Ahmad Ragab below is correct.

There was indeed something wrong with my `assemblyMergeStrategy`, leading to a malformed output JAR. To the limited extent of my understanding, I believe I was clobbering some important metadata with the overly aggressive wildcard in `assemblyMergeStrategy`. The version that works is as follows.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "inject", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("mime.types") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Notably, I tried this once before, and it somehow didn't work. My suspicion, although I cannot prove it retroactively, is that I was accidentally testing that change with a stale build artifact, and so I was accidentally running an older version without those changes. After cleaning everything and rebuilding with those new changes, it worked as expected.

(Note that the app will still crash on startup due to there being no defined outputs, but of course, that failure is an expected one, and we have removed the unexpected one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something looks potentially strange about that `assemblyMergeStrategy` try:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Second, you may in the assembly options need to explicitly set your main class so that the proper manifest gets created, though to be fair, I can't prove this. In the past I have done the following with some success

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("sparkpoc.KinesisExample")
```

Finally, one way you might confirm that your jar is properly created is executing this:

```
java -classpath ming-spark-poc-assembly-0.1.jar "sparkpoc.KinesisExample"
```

Hopefully, some of this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Per this suggestion, I looked into `assemblyMergeStrategy` again, and ended up resolving the issue. I will elaborate on what happened, so that hopefully, if anyone else hits the same pitfall, they will have more information.

Comment: I commented on the original post with more details as to how to fix `assemblyMergeStrategy`. Thank you again for the suggestion.